# How can I modify this circuit to pickup radio waves better

Tags: amplifier, rf

I want to build a simple detector for cellphone signals nearby and I implemented the following circuit on breadboard:

[image]

Here is my breadboard wiring:

[image: 22]

I've checked the wiring 10 times and seems there is no error in wiring.

The only difference with the original circuit is that I used BC547 instead of 2N3904 and 68 Ohm instead of 82 Ohm for the resistor R3. For loop antenna I used a alligator wire.

The circuit doesn't work when even I turn on off a cellphone at  extreme proximity.

It only worked when I cut the loop and inserted a transformer primary winding in series and turn on a drilling machine very near the circuit.

How can I adjust this circuit to make it more sensitive to electromagnetic pick up?

Comment: The output is seen at LED, right (if no then where)? And what is meant by λ at LED?

Comment: Have you tried it whilst standing on one leg and playing Dixie on the harmonica?

Comment: That long clip lead may not resonate at cellphone frequencies.

Comment: Here is the explanation of the circuit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_M5UYOT7MI

Comment: @Chu I didn't get the message in your humor.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf I tried much smaller loops no luck

Comment: You are simply **expecting too much** from this simple circuit. Cells phones use very high frequencies to communicate and this circuit is not very sensitive to those frequencies. It cannot be as it uses slow transistors and it is just **too simple**. This circuit is just a toy, it might work at close range **and that's it**. You should not expect more from it because it simply cannot deliver. Extending the antenna is no use either as that would only decrease the sensitivity at high frequencies.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Is it possible to mahe a tunable LRC circuit like tank circuit across the loop and try that way? How would that be done in practice?

Comment: People do use opamps to detect cellphones, but the transistors inside (modern) opamps usually are very fast (very tiny individual FET stripes or bipolar emitters) and can respond to 2Ghz energy.

Comment: I think I need to find an opmap for RF signals for amplification.

Comment: Also forget building anything that is expected to respond at GHz frequencies on plug in breadboard like that, the parasitics will kill any chance of the thing working (Not that that circuit ever really held out much hope).

Comment: What do you think about this project and opamp used: https://electrosome.com/mobile-phone-detector-circuit/ ?

Comment: Im not sure how he managed to amplify GHz RF with CA3130. The bandwidth of this opamp is enough?

Comment: *...make a tunable LRC circuit like tank circuit across the loop and try that way?* The antenna loop will be part of the tank so you will not get it to work at right frequency. As fas as I know **no one** uses loop antennas at cellphone frequencies because **it simply doesn't work**. *How would that be done in practice?* Not, as it cannot work that way. I suggest you find a book about RF circuit design and learn how it is done. All the suggestions given above, including using opamps, are pointless. The sensitivity will be poor as these circuits are all "hacks".

Comment: And oh, I worked on and have been involved with RF receivers from 150 MHz to 80 GHz so I do know what it takes to build a proper, sensitive receiver. Cellphones generally use frequencies between 800 MHz and 2.4 GHz. The CA3130 barely manages a few MHz, it is **slow** and it is **ancient** also for **real RF** you simply cannot use an opamp. The CA3130 circuit relies on the circuit being **disturbed** by the phone's RF transmissions. It does not actually receive nor amplify the RF signals.

Answer (score 2):

This circuit is a bistable flip-flop. It's tried to get triggered with the voltage that the loop happens to catch. The transistors, which are general purpose switching transistors do not rectify cellphone's GHz-range signals. Using high capacitance and inductance breadboard finishes the result. GHz-range signals allow only few millimeter long wires except when they are specially designed transmission lines.

You need properly designed antenna for your cellphone band, and a crystal detector for that frequency. Then you must in practice test how much DC voltage you can get from the detector, when you tune the antenna. Finally you need a comparator circuit which gets triggered when the inputted DC is high enough. Anything after the diode detector can be on a breadboard, but the rf parts cannot.

I cannot give any proper schematic nor component values because I should do the same practical tests myself to be sure. Search for "Cellphone detector".

One example: https://www.electronicshub.org/cell-phone-detector-circuit/

It at least uses diode detector.

ADD: Detecting radio signals has been under interest about 150 years. Many practical devices has been developed. One example from year 1901:

https://patents.google.com/patent/US755840

**Unwanted cellphone detection** by audio systems should be familiar for everyone. Obviously some common amplifier ICs can rectify cellphone signals and audio circuitry can accidentally be proper antenna. Unfortunately no design cannot be based on knowlwdge that sparse. If you have some well working simple IC based audio amplifier, connect a few centimeter wire (=antenna) directly to the input pin of the IC and check, what you get when you have a transmitting cellphone. It's well possible that you find something usable.